# How can I directly output the type of a variable in gdb if it is not memory?

Tags: python, gdb

While trying to develop a `gdb` plugin in Python, I encountered the following error while trying to directly get the type of a variable.

```
(gdb) p appendLock->owner                                                                                                                
$2 = (Arachne::ThreadContext *) 0x7ff620001a40
(gdb) whatis appendLock->owner                                                                                                           
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
(gdb) ptype appendLock->owner                                                                                                            
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

Is there any workaround for this problem, so that one can directly obtain the type of a variable?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is a direct way to do this using the Python API, which bypasses this problem.

```
(gdb) python print gdb.parse_and_eval("appendLock->owner").type
Arachne::ThreadContext *
```